# How long does it take to get used to the keyboard of the MacBook 12"?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I'm thinking of getting the MacBook 12" but I'm really scared I won't be able to get used to the keyboard. I'm in The Netherlands, it's not possible to return the product.

How long does it take to get used to the keyboard for people here and is there a really big difference once you're typing on it?

Comment: I've decided to buy it and force myself to get used to the keyboard. Returning it is not possible.

Comment: Oh dear. I hate to offer an opinion, but I love the MacBook keyboard but knowing I had a return period reduced my anxiety greatly buying it so soon after launch. Good luck and hopefully you don't decide to sell it used once you make your adjustment period.

Comment: I purchased it and I love it! I really thought it was going to be a problem, but I actually prefer this keyboard after using it for a couple of hours. I think I'm going to use this MacBook for a long time! Thanks guys.

Comment: Now, you'll feel that all laptop keyboard are puny pogo stick keys - even the physical keyboard from Apple feels like meh/blah. I'm ruined and want large butterfly keys on all my keyboards. Enjoy the NVMe storage efficiency and speed too. I can't wait till Mac Pro and iMacs get NVMe and thunderbolt 3. I'm pulling the hold so you can review it.

Comment: Yep, I have exactly the same thing now! I'll go ahead and answer my own question, if that's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally started typing as fast as I would on a 'normal' keyboard after about five minutes. You'll really get used to it in a very short time!

Answer (score 0):

If you can, go to your local Best Buy or Apple Store and check it out. I've only used one at Best Buy, but I think that I'd get used to it pretty quickly. Everyone is different, so YMMV. Just make sure you can return it if you just can't get used to it.

Comment: I did try it out, but I didn't manage to get used to it 100% in the 20 minutes I could be there... in The Netherlands we can't return Apple products unfortunately.

Comment: If you don't mind sacrificing a little portability for more power, you might get the MacBook Pro, instead. It's around the same price, has Force Touch, same old keyboard, and is a lot more powerful. Plus, the Retina ones are still pretty thin, I'm sure you've seen them in person.

Answer (score 0):

I've owned the Macbook 12" for several months and I'm still not used to the keyboard. I'm a seasoned touch typist but there are keys I keep missing, and some keys that were initially not fully responding on all edges and required some continual tapping to get them fully working. the lower right corner of the spacebar has inconsistent response.

The result is that typing feels like a bit of a chore. I've tried positioning my hands in a more extended manner which seem to help a bit. Bottom line is that I prefer the older keyboard style and actually continue to miss my Macbook 11" even though the screen and resolution options are so much better with the Macbook 12".